# How can I manipulate the value in key-value pair inside loop in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, key-value

This is an example:

```
key_value={"a":"test a","b":"test b updated"}
key_value.each do |k,v|
  {
    k=>v+"extra" 
    #or   
    k=>(v=method(v))
    #trying to add some extra values or by changing v value calling some method 

  }
end
```

but I am not able to manipulate the value(v) inside loop.How can I do that any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 {a: 1, b: 2}
```

=> {:a=>10, :b=>20}

```
x.each_pair do |key, value|
    x[key] = value * 10
end
```

=> {:a=>10, :b=>20}

Is this what you meant by, changing values?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try that

```
key_value={"a":"test a","b":"test b updated"}
key_value.each do |k,v|
  {
    key_value[k] = v+"extra" 
  }
end
```